# How to separate methods into different files and than bundle them in one file to require this

Tags: node.js, require

let's imagine you wanna build a file that contains different methods. For example: file `bundler.js` that need method `a()`, `b()`, `c()`. But these methods are very complex and take much lines of code, so it would be nice to separate those methods into there own files. So you have the files `a.js`, `b.js` and `c.js`. 
File `a.js` would look like:

```
module.exports = {
    a: data => console.log(data)
}
```

File b and c look exactly the same and now you want to use them in the `bundle.js` file.

My problem: they all are related to the same instance -> `Bundle()` presented by `bundle.js`, but when I require them in `bundle.js` they all would have the same variable name to follow a logical declaration.

```
let bundle = require('./a.js');
let bundle = require('./b.js');
let bundle = require('./c.js');

bundle.a();
bundle.b();
bundle.c();
```

But when I understand nodejs (and some other programming languages I guess) right, that wouldn't work. I would need a seperate layer that bundles this methods and exports it again. So I require this layer once and would have access to all methods. But I don't know how that layer would look like.

Can someone help me?

Many thanks in advice.

Answer (score 0):

Ok a couple things to note here to start.  1) Your `require` statements aren't being done correctly.  The variable `bundle` is basically being overwritten each time you require.  You would have do something like:

```
let bundleA = require('./a.js');
let bundleB = require('./b.js');
let bundleC = require('./c.js');
```

This way, your `bundle` variable isn't being overwritten each time.  Now, on to what you are actually asking about.  You would want to make a file, in this case called `bundle.js` that would look something like this:

```
// your bundle.js
const a = require('./a.js')
const b = require('./b.js')
const c = require('./c.js')    

exports.bundledA = function() {
   return a;
}

exports.bundledB = function() {
   return b;
}

exports.bundledC = function() {
   return c;
}
```

Now you have a `bundle.js` you can include.  So the next step would be to use it, something like this:

```
// Some file
const bundle = require('./bundle')

// Using method A
bundle.bundledA()
```

Hopefully all that makes sense.  If you have any questions please feel free to say so in the comment and I'll try to explain as best I can.  There's also a link here for exporting and creating your own modules you should read up on:

https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/

Happy coding :-)

Comment: No I'm very sorry. That wouldn't work I always get the error that the required function is not a function :(

Comment: Which required function is not a function?  Can you post the specific error so I can fix the answer to work for you?